# jQuery - use element id to call existing variable of same name...?

Tags: jquery, variables

I have found a few posts that seem similar to what I need, but none seem to solve my problem.

I have a set of variables containing data arrays. For example:

```
var data1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I have elements on the page with id's that match those variable names.

```
<li id="data1">Data 1</li>
```

I want to be able to click on the `<li>` element, and call the associated variable.
How do I use the variable data1 by clicking on the element with an id of data1...?

As a basic example, let's say I want to alert the contents of the data1 array.
I start with something like this:

```
$('li').click(function() {
   dataID = $(this).attr('id');

   alert( ...? ); // <- how do I get the contents of the variable data1 now that I know the clicked element's id was 'data1'?
});
```

Comment: In case if it is from some other external resource and if the data1 is defined in global scope `<script>var data1 = [1,2,3,4,5];</script>` then you can do `window[dataID]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you store the variable on an object, you can reference it easily using array notation.

```
var dataObj = {};
dataOjb.data1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$('li').click(function() {
   alert( dataObj[this.id] );
});
```

Comment: `dataID = $(this).attr('id');` -> `dataID = this.id;`

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `eval(dataID)` in order to call your variable, but I would recommend storing your values in an object instead. In matter of fact do not use `eval` unless absolutely necessary. Storing your values in a object is preferable.